# How to install the older version of Unity on Unity Hub?

Tags: software-installation, unity3d

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, and I want to install Unity 2019.4.2f which my team uses.

But I can't find the older version, but only the latest version 2019.4.5f1(LTS) on the install page of Unity Hub.
[image]

The Unity Hub installation link in [Unity Archive website](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive) is also not working. And I can't find the installion file for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Older versions can be found on Unity's website: https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive. Once you click the download link, it will prompt you to install on your Unity Hub.

What do you mean by the unity archive not working?

Comment: It does not prompt the installation when clicking the download link. It seems that the link to Hub is broken in my environment.